# Multiply all function params

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a function that will multiply all parameters passed into it. The amount of parameters that can be passed to the function can vary. So far I have this

```
var multiply = function () {
    var i, sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        sum *= arguments[i];
    }
    return sum;
};
```

When I call it like this - `multiply(10, 5, 5)` - It returns 0 when the answer should be 250 (10 x 5 x 5). What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `0` times anything is `0`. Start with `sum = 1`

Comment: `sum = 1` This should help

Comment: Thats it! Many thanks

Comment: var  sum = 1 , set 'sum' as 1

Comment: you can do it in a more functional style just by doing a *reduce*: `arguments.reduce(function(x, y) { return x * y })`.

check out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: @mfirry, you will get an error if you try `arguments.reduce`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiplying any number with `0` is `0`.

So set `var sum = 1;`

Answer (score 2):

You could do it also by using [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) :

> The reduce() method applies a function against an accumulator and each value of the array (from left-to-right) to reduce it to a single value.

It does not really have a benefit over the for loop except that you make clear that you want to accumulate the value by using a function that is intended for this.

```
var multiply = function () { 
  return Array.prototype.reduce.call(arguments, function(a, b) { 
    return a * b;
  });
};
```

You need to use the `Array.prototype.reduce.call` construct because `arguments` is only an array like object it most environments.

Answer (score 1):

Since ES6 the answer would be =>

```
const multiply = (..args) => args.reduce((accum, val) => accum * val, 1);
```